# Alt-Tab not working for guest operating systems in Virtualbox on Fedora 25

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard, alt-tab

I do lots of research on net but I couldn't find any solution to my problem.

My host machine is Fedora 25 and I have two guest OS (Kali Linux and Windows 10). Both in my guest OSs every shortcut works properly(Ctrl+C etc.). But alt+tab and Windows key shortcuts doesn't work for guest os. Even i activate or deactivate host key (Right Ctrl) it still tabs between programs in host os. Please help me?

Comment: We're you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

For now, as discussed [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1701105#p1701105), it looks like Windows Key + Alt + Tab does the trick

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a Wayland problem (https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97333). Switching back to X11 solves the problem (on Debian Buster, uncomment #WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf, look for a similar file in Fedora)